# How are z table values calculated

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power

How are values from z tables calculated? For example, $Z(0.2) = -0.842$ but I have no idea where that comes from.

Comment: What does 'Z of the power' mean? Can you give some background information where you are getting this terminology from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is calculated from the Gaussian/Normal distribution as the value $z$ at which the integral from $-\infty$ to $z$ reaches $0.2$:
$$
0.2 = \int_{-\infty}^{z} N(0,1)
$$
This evaluates to $-0.842$.

The integral is calculating the area under the normal distribution from $-\infty$ to $z$ which becomes $0.2$ at $z=-0.842$.

[image]

See [here](https://www.statisticshowto.com/tables/z-table/) for more information.

Comment: The question asked was _how_ the values in the table are determined. Are they determined by numerical integration? Using an _approximation_ formula such as those found in Abramowitz and Stegun?